# How to build Android binaries of linux command line programs (Linux file tool in this case)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to compile the source code of Linux file program into an Android binary (single executable file) using ndk and Android Studio. (source code for Linux file program is available at ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/file-5.38.tar.gz)

The source code does not contain any cmake files and I have difficulty compiling it. Can anyone suggest how this can be done?

Thank you